# How to check if document exists in firestore security rules list request?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have two root collections, `users` and `workspaces`. A user document has a workspaces array with the workspace document IDs the user is a part of. Below is the security rule I try to use. I had two approaches, one is to get the user document from the root collection and check its workspaces array for the workspaceId the other is to check for existance of the userId in the members subcollection. Both end up throwing the same error: `FirebaseError:  Null value error. for 'list' @ L15`
If I separate the allow read into allow get and allow list and just write true for list it fixes the error but obviously I want to restrict the access so users can only get their own workspaces (where they are members).

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /workspaces/{workspaceId} {
      allow read: if isLoggedIn() && userIsInWorkspace(workspaceId);
    }

    function isLoggedIn() {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function userIsInWorkspace(workspaceId) {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/workspaces/$(workspaceId)/members/$(request.auth.uid));
    }
  }
}
```

Approach with get:

```
function userIsInWorkspace(workspaceId) {
      let workspacesOfUser = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.workspaces;
      return workspaceId in workspacesOfUser;
    }
```

UPDATE:

I tried implementing it with custom claims like this:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if isLoggedIn() && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /workspaces/{workspaceId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isLoggedIn() && userIsInWorkspace(workspaceId);
    }

    function isLoggedIn() {
      return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
    }

    function userIsInWorkspace(workspaceId) {
      return workspaceId in request.auth.token.workspaces;
    }
  }
}
```

So my concept was that I have `users` and `workspaces` as rootcollections and `workspaces` has subcollections such as `teams` and `reports` and so on. I still get the same `null value error`. When this comes up is in the above mentioned error so `list` requests does the error. My use case is that when you are logged out from the app the workspace slug that is stored on every workspace entry in firestore gets added az a query parameter so the user can be redirected back to the exact workspace. To make this happen I do a list request so basically I query the workspaces collection where the slug is the given slug from the url.

```
const workspaceSnapshot = await db
          .collection('workspaces')
          .where('slug', '==', this.$route.query.slug)
          .limit(1)
          .get()
```

This request creates my error but from this I cannot make out anything. I would suppose that when I give a condition for reads and writes that includes `get` and `list` as well.

Comment: Can you include the line throwing the error? The `'list' @ L15`.

Comment: It was the line: allow read: if isLoggedIn() && userIsInWorkspace(workspaceId) I just deleted some comments and rules not connected to the issue so that is why the line number is not correct

Comment: Can you include the query you are trying to perform? Remember that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters) - if you are trying to do `db.collection('workspaces').get().then(...)` it will always fail if any of the workspaces in `/workspaces` aren't readable by the requesting user.

Comment: I think you might be right. I tried this:  `const workspaceSnapshot = await db.collection('workspaces').where('slug', '==', this.$route.query.slug).get()`. Currently in my local setup all workspaces fulfill the rules criteria however later on this could cause a problem because my idea was to filter out the workspaces with a where and if the user tries to modify it to return other workspaces then the security rule should have stopped it. If this is not possible then I guess I might have to get the workspaces one by one. Am I right?

Comment: If you store the workspace's ID in the workspace document, you can fetch workspaces by their ID in batches of 10 using an [`in` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

Comment: Yes but a user can easily exceed 10 workspaces, then do I just split them into batches of 10 and get them?

Comment: @samthecodingman I updated my question with some more details and findings, if you could take another look I would be really grateful!

Comment: The in clause  can give you more than 10 workspaces, the thing that @samthecodingman told you is that with in you can only combine ten in clauses in the same query. ['Use the in operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) the clause in does not restrict the number of results.

Answer (score 1):

Queries are case-sensitive. You said you had two root collections, namely `Users` and `Workspaces`, but you are querying against `users` and `workspaces`. This will not yield results. Try changing your query:

```
function userIsInWorkspace(workspaceId) {
      let workspacesOfUser = get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.workspaces;
      return workspaceId in workspacesOfUser;
}
```

Comment: You are right, but that is just a mistake I made here, my collections are written with lowercase in my emulator db as well. I edited my question to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on the Rules Playground.

Comment: Do you think this could be a problem with the emulator?

Comment: Possibly. What version are you using?

Comment: firebase is 8.0.0 and security rule version 2 but I think you have seen that is there any other thing I should check?